# HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I published a website and created a website in IIS, as you can see here:

[image: IIS Site Binding]

But when I enter the url `conf.qums.ac.ir`, I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

[image: Error Page]

As you can see in the image the browser redirects the request to the ip of server

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I did this:

- Open IIS Manager
- Right click on Default Website
- Click Manage Web Site
- Click Start

Everything should work now

I hope it is ok.